# Question about notation of expectation operators over multiple random processes

Tags: multilevel-analysis, notation, mathematical-statistics

My question is what are suitable or accepted notations for taking expectations over multiple random processes in the same equation.

Let a model for variable $y$ be given by $$y_{i \alpha}=\mu_i+\epsilon_{i \alpha}$$

measured on multiple individuals $i$ and on repeated measurement occasions $\alpha$, so that $\epsilon_{\alpha i}$ is measurement error of $i$ on $y_i$ at occasion $\alpha$.

How should I denote the expecation operator over measurement occasions $\alpha$ but not $i$? I thought of something like $$E_{\alpha}[\epsilon_{i \alpha}]=\beta_i$$ (so measurement error $\beta_i$ contributed by $i$ on each occasion). Or would it be better to use $E_i$ instead? I think I have also seen notation $E[\epsilon_{i \alpha}|i]$, but I find this counterintuitive ($i$ is not a random variable, so why condition on it?).

Finally the question would be how to denote expectation over both $i$ and $\alpha$, for example $E_{i \alpha}[\epsilon_{i \alpha}]=\beta$ or rather $E[\epsilon_{i \alpha}|{i,\alpha}]$.

Comment: Are you asking about *expectation* or--as it appears--about *arithmetic means* of data or random variables?

Comment: I am not sure. Isn't arithmetic mean the finite population (or sample) equivalent of the expectation?

Comment: I mean, in theory there can be both infinite replications over measurement occasions and the population can be inifnite. Hence it makes sense to conceptualize $y$ as having a distribution both over trials as well as over inviduals. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: There is an important difference between "arithmetic mean" and "expectation" both in terms of modeling and concepts. The arithmetic mean is an expectation *only* when you assume the data describe the values of a discrete distribution with uniform probabilities. Confusing "arithmetic mean" with "expectation" causes one to try to use the same notation for both, leading to ambiguity and notational difficulties.  My first comment was an implicit suggestion that focusing on this distinction might help you out and perhaps lead to a simple answer to your question.